# What is known about nice automorphisms of the Mandelbrot set?

Tags: fractals

It is often stated that fractals, such as the Mandelbrot set M, are self-similar, although I've never heard of any functions to formally model this perspective.

I'm curious to learn about any functions f that map M to itself in nontrivial ways. By "nice" in the title, I mean to exclude trivial or very artificial functions that fail to provide any insight into the structure of M (so "nice" is being used informally).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mandelbrot set is not [self-similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similar) in the sense that you mean -- that applies more to fractals like the [Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle), the [Koch curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake), and so forth.  There are several subsets of the Mandelbrot set that are approximately similar to the Mandelbrot set, as shown in this zoom sequence from Wikipedia:

[image: Quasi-self-similarity of the Mandelbrot set]

The Mandelbrot set is also infinitesimally self-similar at any [Misiurewicz point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misiurewicz_point), in the sense that zooming in at such a point reveals local structure that seems to repeat the farther you zoom in.  (In fact, the local structure is converging to the local structure of the corresponding [Julia set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set).)

As a general rule, not all fractals are self-similar, though self-similarity is a common property of simple fractal shapes.  There is not a single widely-accepted definition of fractal within mathematics, though it is generally agreed that any shape with non-integer [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) is a fractal.  The Mandelbrot set has Hausdorff dimension 2, but it is still considered a fractal because of its complicated local structure and approximate self-similarities.

If you are looking for some insight into the structure of $M$, here's a good way to proceed:

1. Learn about the [main cardioid and period bulbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#The_main_cardioid_and_period_bulbs), and possibly the antennas as well.  ([This article](http://plus.maths.org/content/os/issue40/features/devaney/index) by Bod Devaney might be a good place to start.)
2. Learn something about postcritically finite quadratics, and their relationship to hyperbolic components and Misiurewicz points.
3. Learn about [external rays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ray) and [Bötcher coordinates](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~buff/Preprints/Bottcher/Bottcher.pdf) on the complement.
4. Learn about tuning and renormalization.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting links, @Jim.  Is there any particular reason to think such functions M->M don't exist?

Comment: I think this is what tuning and renormalization are about. The resulting functions are not similarity transformations, but they do explain the quasi-self-similarity of the Mandelbrot set.